# How should we test our application in Docker container?

Tags: automated-tests

We have a Java Application in a Docker Container with a Docker Db2 database 'side-car'.  In DevOps pipeline (Jenkins) we run unit tests, and integration test between components.  Run SonarQube and if all good, we move over to the Staging environment.  In the Automated Testing step we build application container using latest code base, we then proceed to run automated Acceptance Testing using Cucumber framework.

Question is about the use of database for testing:  should we spin up a db2 in a new/isolated container, or use a 'common' DB2 container that the test team uses in that env for manual testing?  Best practices, proven approaches and recommendations are needed.

Answer (score 0):

for post deployment tests (API tests, end to end tests), I would try to avoid using the same db with other environments and have dedicated database setup for those tests.

The reasons are:

- For API tests, end to end tests, I want to have control on what data is available in database. If sharing database with other environments, the tests can fail for strange reason (.e.g. someone accidentally modify the record that the test is expecting to be in some state)
- For the same reason, I don't want the API tests, end to end tests to affect other people testing also. It will be quite annoying if someone is in the middle of testing and realise the data is wiped out by post deployment tests

So normally in the CI, we have steps to:

- clear test db
- run migration
- seed essential data
- deploy server
- run post deployment tests

Comment: Thank you Phuong.